# Fast computation for changing the leftmost different bit

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

Given the two number in 8-bit:

```
x = 0b11110111
y = 0b11001010
```

What I want to do is to compare x and y and change x only the first different leftmost bit based on y. For example:

```
z = 0b11010111 (Because the leftmost different bit between x and y is in the third place, therefore, change the third bit in x based on y and other remain the same.)
```

And my code is:

```
flag = True
for i in range(8):
    if flag and x[i] != y[i]: # Change only the left-most different bit.
        flag = False
    else:
        y[i] = x[i] # Otherwise,  remain the same.
```

This could work find.

Buit the problem is if I have many pairs like:

```
for (x, y) in nums:
    flag = True
    for i in range(8):
        if flag and x[i] != y[i]: # Change only the left-most different bit.
            flag = False
        else:
            y[i] = x[i] # Otherwise,  remain the same.
```

When nums is large, then this process will be really slow.
So how can I improve the process of the problem?

BTW, this is the project of the deep learning task, so it can run on GPU, but I don't know whether it can be paralleled by GPU or not.

Comment: You provide the example `x = 11110111`, but I assume you really meant `x = 0b11110111`? What if `x` and `y` don't have the same number of bits? (or leading 0's, depending on how you look at it - and if you consider that leading zeroes, how do you determine the byte-size of `x` and `y`?)

Comment: @Grismar Yes I meant ```x = 0b11110111```. Here I only consider 8-bit. So x and y will be in the same size. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you're after:

```
from math import floor, log2


def my_fun(x, y):
    return x ^ (2 ** floor(log2(x ^ y)))


z = my_fun(0b11110111, 0b11001010)
print(f'{z:b}')
```

Output:

```
11010111
```

The function does the following:

- compute the XOR result of `x` and `y`, which will include the most significant bit where they differ as the most significant bit to be 1
- compute the `floor` of the `log2` of that value, and raising `2` to that power, to get a number that only has that bit set to 1
- return the XOR of `x` and that number, flipping the relevant bit

Comment: This is a wonderful solution!!! Thank for your help.